# Wait for all child process to exit

Tags: c, unix, pipe, wait

I am trying to code a shell pipe in c but my program don't wait all child before finish.

```
int fd[2];
if (fork() == 0)
{
    dup2(fd[1], 1);
    close(0);
    execlp("ls", "ls, NULL);
}
if (fork() == 0)
{
    dup2(fd[1], 1);
    close(0);
    execlp("wc" "wc", NULL);
}
wait(NULL);//this dont wait all child
//wait(NULL); wait(NULL); this go into infinite loop
//while (wait(NULL) > 0); this go into infinite loop
write(1, "test", 4);
```

If I use `wait(NULL)`, "test" is displayed in the middle of wc's output and if I use while `(wait(NULL) > 0)`; it goes into an infinite loop.

**Edit** : The solution was to close the pipe (`close(fd[0]); close(fd[1]);`) before the wait. I'll edit again if I understand how this work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each call of `wait(2)` blocks the parent-process untill one of its children exits. So if you want to block the parent-process untill all children exit, you have to call `wait()` in a for loop as many times as your children processes are.

`while (wait(NULL) > 0)` won't work because `wait()` returns the PID of the child-process caught, so it's always true, causing an infinite loop.

Comment: So if I have two child, I should do two `wait` ? This also goes into infinite loop :\